# C# client SocketIoClientDotNet.Client is not work(node server)

Tags: c#, node.js, socket.io

C# WinForms client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;

namespace socket_TEST
{
#nullable enable
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect();
    }

    public void connect()
    {
        var socket = IO.Socket("http://127.0.0.1:3000/");

        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("connection!");
        });
        socket.On("connection", () =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("connection!");
        });

    }
 }
}
```

Nodejs server:

```
const app=require('express')();
const server=require('http').Server(app);
const io=require('socket.io')(server);

io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
    console.log("new client");
});

server.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("------SERVER RUNNING------");
});
```

I want to connect C# and Nodejs servers.

But the connection is still not working. Can you tell me why and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see SocketIoClientDotNet THIS PROJECT IS DEPRECATED